# How to test authentication using mocks?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm doing an exercise where testing is a task, and I should use mockito to test the methods.
I'm trying to test if the authentication is succesful, but I always get expection, saying

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(any());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
```

I'm not sure what it means, or how should I handle this, because I'm a beginner in testing.
The app looks like this:

Tester class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)

public class Tester {

@Mock
Player loggedPlayer =  new Player(null,null,null,BigDecimal.valueOf(200),Currency.EUR);

@InjectMocks
DefaultSportsBettingService service = new DefaultSportsBettingService();

@Test
public void testAuthenticateUserIsSuccesful(){
    DefaultSportsBettingService service = mock(DefaultSportsBettingService.class);
    User user = new User("asd","123");
    Player logged = service.authenticateUser(user);

    when(service.authenticateUser(any(User.class))).thenReturn(any());
    verify(service, times(1)).authenticateUser(user);
    assertNotEquals(null, logged);
}
```

Service class:

```
public class DefaultSportsBettingService implements SportsBettingService{

public DummyDataStore dds = new DummyDataStore();
public List <Player> initializedPlayers = dds.getPlayerDatastore();
public List<User> initializedUsers = dds.getUserDataStore();
public List<Outcome> outcomeDatastore = dds.getOutcomeDatastore();
public List<SportEvent> sportEventDataStore = dds.getSportEventDataStore();
public List<Wager> wagerDatastore = dds.getWagerDatastore();
public List<Bet> betsDataStore = dds.getBetDataStore();
public Player loggedPlayer;

@Override
public Player authenticateUser(User login) throws AuthenticationException {
    Player find = new Player();

    for (Player player : initializedPlayers) {
            if (login.getEmail().equals(player.getEmail()) && login.getPassword().equals(player.getPassword())) {
                loggedPlayer = player;

            return loggedPlayer;
            }
    }
    throw new AuthenticationException("Incorrect email and/or password");
}
```

Player class:

```
public class Player extends User{
private String name;

private BigDecimal balance;

private Currency currency;

public Player(){

}
public Player(String email, String password, String name, BigDecimal balance, Currency currency) {
    super(email, password);
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.currency = currency;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public BigDecimal getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public Currency getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}

public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {
    this.currency = currency;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Player{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", balance=" + balance +
            ", currency=" + currency +
            '}';
}
}`
```

User class:

```
public class User{
private String email;
private String password;

public User(){

}

public User(String email, String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Can someone explain how it works, please?

EDIT:
Currently, I'm using this logic:

```
 @Test
public void testAuthenticateUserIsSuccesful(){
    DefaultSportsBettingService service = new DefaultSportsBettingService();
    User user = new User("asd","123");
    Player logged = service.authenticateUser(user);
    assertNotEquals(null, logged);
}
```

Comment: `thenReturn(any())` is the Problem, I think you want `thenReturn(loggedPlayer)`. And loggedPlayer isn't a Mock. But then you just test Mocking. You usually mock the objects that are used in `authenticateUser`

Comment: @Turo Thank your for your kind help. I will try out your logic aswell, however I managed to solve it in my own way. Do you think the following test method is good enough for its purpose? I put it in the end of the original post

Comment: Since you are testing the 'real' DummyDataStore(that's what in the sources) its ok. It's the Datastore that needs to mocked when a database or another service is used...